# git status with tag information

Tags: git, tags

When I use `git status` it shows the current branch I'm in or the commit if it is detached. Is there any way to show the tags for the current commit? I know about `git describe` and `git tag`, what I would like to know is if there is any way to show the tag information when calling `git status`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any way to get that information from `git status`, but `git show` or `git show HEAD` will provide it. You can also give `--decorate` to `git log` to have it print that information on the history as well.

This command will show one line of output, including the tags:

```
git show --format=oneline --no-patch
```

And this command will show just the tags and branches that point to HEAD:

```
git show --format=%d --no-patch
```